# Python-MySQLdb: Difficulty In Creating Table

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am facing a problem while creating a table in mysqldb using python like this:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s ( tweetId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, tweet VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(tweetId) )",('Tutulive')) .
```

I am getting this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Tutulive' ( tweetId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, tweet VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, PRIMARY' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL parameters should not be used for metadata. Sanitize the value yourself and insert it into the string normally.

Comment: What do you mean by sanitize ?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/what-does-sanitized-mean-in-api-documentation